# How to get an access token from vKontakte (VK) via OAuth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, vk

I'm trying to get an access token from vKontakte (russian social network) via [their OAuth2 API](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile).
This is how I make the call:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=12345&scope=wall,offline&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/oauth/vk.php&display=page&v=5.24&response_type=token
```

I'm receiving an access token but if I try to post a message with it, I'm receiving this error:

```
//error: Permission to perform this action is denied for non-standalone applications: you should request token using blank.html page.
```

My app is a standalone application - why do I receive the error?

Answer (score 3):

I see that your "client_id" is '12345'  - is it a fake ID, or a real one? Did you get a valid client_id from VK?

It appears that you should request the token via "blank.html":

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=<app_id>&scope=...,wall,...&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&response_type=token
```

(instead of vk.php, in your example)

Comment: It's a fake one, I received a valid one from VK.

Comment: I'm not getting a token but a warning from VK: `Please do not copy the data from the address bar to third-party sites. So you can lose access to your account.`

Comment: maybe it is hard-coded in VK side, so you should redirect to blank.html in your app. for example: ...redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/oauth/blank.html... instead of vk.php.

Comment: create a page in your app, blank.html, and try again.

Comment: @OhadR I'm looking for a solution for this too. Isn't it required to use the VK URL `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html` for the redirect in order to receive the token or am I wrong? Can you please explain it further or show me an example?

Comment: I dont really have a specific example for VK, but this is how oAuth works. Maybe they have examples in the documentations in their website...

Answer (score 2):

The steps that you have followed are correct.

The warning message `Please do not copy the data from the address bar to third-party sites. So you can lose access to your account.` will be displayed on the screen. Whereas, the actual access token will be found on the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what it says it is - you cannot use implicit flow for non-standalone application. Instead, you should use authorization code flow, which is more secure for client applications.

Answer (score 0):

After long research, I understood that the access_token which allows posting on a user's wall is in the URL of this page https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html whereas on this page an alert which says to the user

> Please do not copy the data from the address bar to third-party sites.
> So you can lose access to your account.

so as a developer I have to convince the user that vk is wrong and that you must give the access_token ...
Total confusion ... it's stupid how it works